# Explorer compatibility with blockchain node version v1.0.0

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, pallet-contracts, substrate-contracts-node, explorer

The issue I ran in is finding an explorer version, which is compatible with substrate version v1.0.0.

I found that version of explorer below v0.133.1 (https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/releases/tag/v0.133.1) are not compatible with the contracts pallet in v1.0.0, however when testing v0.133.1 or above, I encountered the following errors:

In accounts page:

- `RPC-CORE: subscribeStorage(keys?: Vec<StorageKey>): StorageChangeSet:: createType(Vec<StorageKey>):: Expected an array of 1 values as params to a Map query`
- `Error: useCall(...):: createType(Vec<StorageKey>):: Expected an array of 1 values as params to a Map query:: Error: createType(Vec<StorageKey>):: Expected an array of 1 values as params to a Map query`

When deploying a contract:

- ````
   --> starting at object with constructor 'EventEmitter'
   |     property '_events' -> object with constructor 'Events'
   |     property 'ready' -> object with constructor 'EE'
   --- property 'context' closes the circle ```
  ````
- And the tx status bar keeps spinning
- Address counter is not incremented though contract is deployed and I managed to interact with it just fine
- Though, sometimes the I can't interact with contract, as address does seem to be recognised as one belonging to a contract

General warning: `Unable to map [u8; 32] to a lookup index`

Question:
What would be the solution to issues described above? are there bugs within v1.0.0 node version, which were fixed later?
If there is an explorer version I should target, it's also an option, however I tried many commits and couldn't find the right one.

Thanks